# How to assign File to InputStream?

Tags: android, fileinputstream

Previously I read a json file from `raw` folder of android `resources`,

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsonfile);

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int ctr;
        try {
            ctr = inputStream.read();
            while (ctr != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(ctr);
                ctr = inputStream.read();
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject jObject = null;
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(
                    byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Gson g = new Gson();

        MyList responseData = g.fromJson(jObject.toString(), MyList.class);

        if (responseData.getPeopleList().size() == 0) {
            //do something
        }
```

Now I need to save that file in external storage of device. I tried instead of 1st line in above segment,

```
File fileJson = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir("/folderName"), "jsonfile.json");

InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileJson);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but now `responseData` is null now. Correct me please

error log is,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: `/folder` is not a valid value for the parameter passed to `getExternalFilesDir()`. Beyond that, what does "This didn't work as I expected" mean? What are your symptoms?

Comment: @CommonsWare elaborated my problem. please check now

Comment: Again, `/folder` is not a valid value for `getExternalFilesDir()`. Where is this file that you are trying to load?

Comment: From external storage of my device ("Android/data/myappfolder")

Comment: but I used
File fileJson = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir("/folderName"), "jsonfile.json");
fileJson .createNewFile();
to create that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Put the file in what you think is `Android/data/myappfolder/files/`. So, you will have `Android/data/myappfolder/files/jsonfile.json`.

Step #2: Use `File fileJson = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "jsonfile.json");`